# Setting Gradient Dynamically does'nt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Changing/Setting a HTML elements gradient on Safari doesn't work.

The following code uses the CSS webkit way of making a gradient which is supposed to work on Safari & Chrome. But it doesn't show the gradient, do you know how I can make it show?

```
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <p id="test">abcdef</p>
    </div>

</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

        var newEle = document.createElement("p"); 
        newEle.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#2F2727), to(#FF0000))";
        newEle.innerHTML = "kjdskjdkgj";
        document.getElementById("mainContent").appendChild(newEle);
    -->
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me Safari doesn't know this syntax. Try

```
newEle.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#2F2727,#FF0000)";
```

instead.